# Broadcast Intents Android

Tags: android

How Good are broadcast intent` in terms of say I wanted to fire broadcast intents ten times a second for half an hour.

Right now I have a service doing this, and it runs perfectly well until the user rotates the screen: then it gets all messed up and stupid and gives errors.

However, broadcast intents are short live objects, so how would these perform in my conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadcast Intents involve cross-process IPC; firing those that quickly for that long will eat quite a bit of battery life. Intents are not designed to be broadcast quite that often.

If your service is getting "messed up" because of a screen rotation, your activity is at fault, perhaps by stopping the service when it shouldn't. Services are not directly affected by screen rotations.

Comment: yea thats what i meant, the activity is messing it up. I solved this problem by using this.getApplication().startService(). its looking good so far